# ActiveMQ: What is DEPENDENCIES file inside lib folder of ActiveMq jars?

Tags: maven, activemq-classic, maven-plugin, dependency-management, maven-assembly-plugin

ActiveMq v 5.10.1

I downloaded ActiveMq.
Went to its lib folder.
Selected and unzipped

```
 activemq-web-5.10.1 and 
 activemq-kahadb-store-5.10.1
```

jars.

Went inside the respective META-INF folders and noticed this file named as DEPENDENCIES.

What is this DEPENDENCIES file ?

It seems related to dependency Management.

What does it do?

Answer (score 0):

After searching with various different keywords, I was eventually able to figure out what is this DEPENDENCIES file.

It comes from Apache-Resource-Bundle. See Here  http://maven.apache.org/apache-resource-bundles/

It is basically a way to ensure that any jar created by Apache is having some standard. For example, it includes License, Disclaimers.

The DEPENDENCIES file simple is a list of Dependencies on which the jar depends in pretty format.

It is not at all involved in dependency management. It is simply of packaging purposes.